# Django choicefield using pictures instead of text not displaying

Tags: html, django, forms, image

I'm trying to do something which should be straightforward, but I cannot have it work properly.

I would like to display images in a grid, with let's say 4-6 images per column and be able to select one and then hit a submit button.

My model looks like:

```
class MyPicture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60,
                            blank=False,
                            unique=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='logos')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My form looks like:

```
class MyPictureForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyPictureForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['pictures'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyPicture.objects.all())
```

My view looks like:

```
def mypicture(request):
    form = MyPictureForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        #TODO

    return render(request, 'myproj/picture.html', {'form': form})
```

and finally, my hmtl (where I assume the issue lies):

```
<form action="{% url 'mypicture' %}" method="post">

    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for s in form.pictures %}
        <option value="{{ s.id }}"><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ s.logo.url }}"/></option>      
    {% endfor %}


    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>

</form>
```

The pictures just don't show up. When I put a breakpoint, in the form I was able to double check that the adresses of the pictures were properly selected.

I'm convinced the error is in the html, but I could not figure out where despite my many attempts.

Maybe with a fresh eye, you'll spot it in seconds... hope so! :)

Best:

Eric

Comment: Are there any errors, in the backend or in the javascript console?

Comment: @rob Thanks for your help. No I don't get errors. That's the worst. :(

Answer (score 0):

you not create a select element in your HTML.

```
<form action="{% url 'mypicture' %}" method="post">

    {% csrf_token %}
    <select name='picture'>
    {% for s in form.pictures.queryset %}
        <option value="{{ s.id }}"><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ s.logo.url }}"/></option>      
    {% endfor %}
    </select>


    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>

</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately nothing displays. It's as if s.logo.url was not recognised. Even doing `{{s.name}}` does not work. The only way for me to get something is by calling `{{s}}`. I'm under the impression the choices are converted to strings before being passed to the html as that is why I cannot use them as objects by calling their attributes (ex: `logo`). What do you think?

Comment: I think that's exactly the problem. When I display the source code of the html, I get lots of empty `<option value=""><img src=""/></option>`.

Comment: you must iterate over all elements in query set of picture field. answer updated

Comment: Unfortunately `queryset` does not seem to be recognised within the html as the loop is empty. It works though in the view just before the template is sent to the html if I put a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you defined `pictures` field in form? Or is your form a `forms.ModelForm` instead of `forms.Form`?
I think you should put that outside `__init__`, or maybe we are missing some part of code.

```
class MyPictureForm(forms.Form):
    pictures = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=MyPicture.objects.all())
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest. Isn't your syntax equivalent to my `__init__`? I tried yours just in case and the problem still remains. :S

Comment: Mmmm.. you might be right. The point is that I think it's cleaner to define fields before calling super `__init__`. So I'd try creating a new widget based on Select widget changing `option_template_name` with your own template. `<option value="{{ widget.value }}"{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}><img src="{{ widget.value }}"/>{{ widget.label }}</option>`.

Answer (score 0):

The answers above is almost right, there is just one thing you should add to code to be it working. In the template instead of `form.pictures.queryset` set `form.fields.pictures.queryset`. Whole example:

models.py:

```
class MyPicture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    logo = models.ImageField()
```

forms.py:

```
class MyPictureForm(forms.Form):
    pictures = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=MyPicture.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(),
    )
```

views.py

```
def showform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass  # do something
    else:
        form = MyPictureForm()
    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'order.html', context=context)
```

template:

```
{% for picture in form.fields.pictures.queryset %}
    {{ picture.logo.url }}
    # also you can access to any field in your model, for example: {{ picture.name }}
{% endfor %}
```