# Using django-select2 for a dropdown list with pictures

Tags: javascript, html, django, jquery-select2

I'm trying to take another approach for the problem I desribed below making use of **django-select2**  module.

[Django choicefield using pictures instead of text not displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52802458/django-choicefield-using-pictures-instead-of-text-not-displaying)

I have a django model which looks like:

My model looks like:

```
class MyPicture(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60,
                            blank=False,
                            unique=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='logos')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I would like to create a drop down looking like

[image]

source: http://select2.github.io/select2/

where essentially I have a big picture on the left (corresponding to what I called logo) and some text on the right (corresponding to name).

My form looks like:

```
from django_select2.forms import Select2MultipleWidget

class MyPictureForm(forms.Form):
    pictures = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=Select2MultipleWidget, queryset=MyPicture.objects.all())
```

My view looks like:

```
def mypicture(request):
    form = MyPictureForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        #TODO

    return render(request, 'myproj/picture.html', {'form': form})
```

and finally, my hmtl (where something is wrong):

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<head>
    {{ form.media.css }}
    <title>In construction</title>
</head>


<form action="{% url 'mypicture' %}" method="post">

    {% csrf_token %}
    <select id="#e4" name="picture">
        {% for x in form.pictures.field.queryset %}
            <option value="{{ x.id }}"><img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ x.logo.url }}" height=150px/></option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Valider" class="btn btn-primary"/>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function format(x) {
            if (!x.id) return x.name; // optgroup
            return "<img src=" + x.logo.url + "/>" + x.name;
        }
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#e4").select2({
                formatResult: format,
                formatSelection: format,
                dropdownCssClass: "bigdrop", // apply css that makes the dropdown taller
                escapeMarkup: function (m) { return m; } // we do not want to escape markup since we are displaying html in results
            });
        });
    </script>
    {{ form.media.js }}
</form>
```

Unfortunately I'm not good enough to tell whether my error is in the javascript or in the loop. When I right click to get the source code, the options are properly set. So I must not be to far from the answer.

It might be trivial for those of you with more javascript experience than me.

Thanks for your help!!

Best:

Eric

Answer (score 0):

I think (most) browsers don't allow anything inside an `<option>`-tag besides plain text.

This is what Mozilla says about the allowed content of `<option>`-tags:

> Permitted content: Text, possibly with escaped characters (like
> é).`

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

Not sure if you can set something as a background though.